# Php single Array Comparison

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays.
For example

```
$arr1 = ['apple','mango','grapes','banana'];
$arr2 = ['apple','mango','orange'];
```

Now I want to compare these two arrays and make it as

```
$arr3 = ['apple','mango','grapes','banana']
```

That is, compare `$arr2` with `$arr1`. If the value of `$arr2` exists(apple and mango) in `$arr1`, then add it in `$arr3` otherwise remove that element from `$arr2` (orange).

Note: `$arr1` values remains the same. i.e - should not remove grapes and banana

I have tried `array_intersect` and `array_unique`. But struck with the logic.

Comment: What code have you tried? What was the output? What was the expected/desired output ?

Comment: I can't see from your description any change of $arr1. I mean `$arr3 = $arr1;` will meet your reqs. Do you need only filter `$arr2`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will do.

```
$arr3 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
$arr4 = array_diff($arr1,$arr3);
$output = array_merge($arr3,$arr4);
```

Comment: But this removing the unique values from $arr1(grapes and banana) also. I just want to keep the $arr1 values as it is. I want to remove the unique values only from $arr2.

Answer (score 0):

@vinothini simply do it with array_intersect() and array_diff() like below:

```
<?php
$arr1 = ['apple','mango','grapes','banana'];
$arr2 = ['apple','mango','orange'];
$arr3 = array_merge(array_intersect($arr2, $arr1), array_diff($arr1, $arr2));
print_r($arr3);
```

But the main thing about your answer is that in your case $arr3 will alway equals to $arr1 you don't have to calculate anything so right answer is:

$`arr3 = $arr1`

you can directly take $arr1 as your desired array()

Comment: $arr3 is always equal to $arr1, no calculation needed